# NO ACTIVATE window style

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I need a window that does not activate when I click on it but is should elsewhere react normal. By  normal I mean if there is a button on it and I click on the button it should execute the  click and call the click function ( or event handle or what so ever). So it should be a normal window except that it shouldn't get activated when you interact with it.
I know you can do this with a message filter or hooks but is there any window style that does this automatically?

this is for windows.

thanks!

Comment: I would show you some sample code, but I'm not sure if you're trying to do this in C++ or C#. Which is your target language?

Comment: I can do it in c / C++ , C# it doesn't mater

Comment: Yes, you can do it in any of the languages. You're saying that you don't care which your program is written in? Do you know how to set extended window styles and process Windows messages?

Comment: i've just tried  WS_EX_NOACTIVATE and it won't activate the window as expected but it also won't execute click on buttons and other stuff. I'll try WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message and came back with some feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [**`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`** extended window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543.aspx)?

> A top-level window created with this style does not become the foreground window when the user clicks it. The system does not bring this window to the foreground when the user minimizes or closes the foreground window.
>
> To activate the window, use the `SetActiveWindow` or `SetForegroundWindow` function.

Otherwise, if that doesn't do what you want, you will need to handle the [`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645612.aspx) and return `MA_NOACTIVATE`.